# Matrix-version of $\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac{a+b}{ab}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my [Linear Algebra Textbook](http://www.amazon.ca/Linear-Algebra-Edition-John-Fraleigh/dp/0201526751) one exercise is to find the matrix analogue of
$$
\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac{a+b}{ab}
$$
my immediate response was
$$
A^{-1}+B^{-1}=A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1}
$$
is that a reasonable answer or do someone have better suggestions?

**NOTE:** $A$ and $B$ are assumed invertible $n\times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a good analogue, especially because it is true.
I doubt there would be a neater one.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose the exercise aims at being aware of the non-commutativity of matrix multiplication ... I am not sure what the point would be apart from that.

Comment: @String, I assume the point is getting used to the multiplicative notation (using $A^{-1}B$ instead of $\frac BA$ so that order is never ambiguous) and being constantly aware that matrices need not commute. But that _is_ a good point in early linear algebra.